# Display HTML text in SWT Label

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I would like to display the HTML text in a Java SWT Label. 
Below is my code for creating a label.

```
Label theLabel = new Label(controls,SWT.WRAP);
theLabel.setSize(100,500);
theLable.setText("<html><ol><li>Hello</li><li>welcome</li></ol></html>");
```

When I run the application as Eclipse Application I get the output as:

```
<html><ol><li>Hello</li><li>welcome</li></ol></html>
```

What is the mistake? Why I am not getting the html formatted output in my label? I am using Eclipse plugin with a view.

Comment: Why you don't use JLabel from **javax.swing.JLabel** ?

Comment: SWT Label don't render HTML.

Comment: *"What is the mistake?"* 1) Adding the [tag:swing] to a question for which it is not relevant. 2) Marking HTML snippets as a runnable code snippet (which is only useful for JS or HTML that is meant for a browser).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show HTML with SWT you will have to use the [Browser widget](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fbrowser%2FBrowser.html) instead.

```java
Browser browser = new Browser( parent, SWT.NONE );
browser.setText( "<html><ol><li>Hello</li><li>welcome</li></ol></html>" );
```

If you don't mind the extra dependency on `org.eclipse.ui.forms` you can also use [FormText](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fforms%2Fwidgets%2FFormText.html). But be aware that the control does only understand a subset of HTML (`<p>`, `<b>`, `<li>`, `<img>`, `<br>`, `<span>`) to render simple formatted text.

Comment: FormText allows automatic conversion of URLs into hyperlinks so is pretty good for showing URLs within strings.