# How to read html on java without jsoup or any other third party?

Tags: java, html, string, parsing, formatting

I have a StringBuilder object in my class which I want to display on UI. This object has few html tags for ex: `<li> <br>` etc. I would like to know how to format this object so that the html tags are not shown as it is on screen, however they are converted to a readable format.

Note: I don't want to remove these tags and get a plain text. Rather if there is a `<br>` tag it should break line while displaying the text. Also, due to project restrictions I don't want to use any third party like jsoup etc.

Any help to achieve this would be appreciated!

Comment: Where (in web page/Swing components/?) do you want to display this text?

Comment: I want to show in SWT component.

Comment: I have no experience with SWT. However, I think you do not have to change your text i.e. SWT can render your text automatically in the way you want e.g. check https://stackoverflow.com/q/32857891/10819573

Answer (score 0):

How about simple `.toString().replaceAll` with specific replacements? Like:

`<br>` = \r\n

`<li>` = \r\n  •

...and so on..

Comment: Yes that's one option but I have lot of tags and lot of strings so looking for some better solution.

Comment: @schaturv If you cannot use suggested solution from Arvind (ie. use Browser component) and dont want to create your own parser, then take source code of existing parser (e.g. mentioned jsoup) and take parts/classes which you will need only.